# Expanding the Ricci tensor by summing over indices

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature, notation

I had an attempt at deriving the Schwarzschild metric. This is a 4-dimensional problem where the indices are being summed from 0 to 3. I got up to the part where I calculate the Ricci tensor which is given by:

$${R_{\mu\nu}}=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu,\lambda}-\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\lambda,\nu}+\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\Gamma^\sigma_{\lambda\sigma}-\Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\lambda}\Gamma^\lambda_{\nu\sigma}$$
I am calculating ${R_{00}}$:
$${R_{00}}=\Gamma^\lambda_{00,\lambda}-\Gamma^\lambda_{0\lambda,0}+\Gamma^\lambda_{00}\Gamma^\sigma_{\lambda\sigma}-\Gamma^\sigma_{0\lambda}\Gamma^\lambda_{0\sigma}$$

How will it look like if I expanded it fully by summing over all the indices from 0 to 3? I tried expanding it but keep getting confused if I should sum over each term separately.

Comment: It's Einstein summation convention, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but keep getting confused if I should sum over each term separately.

It's not particularly clear what you mean here. Your expression uses the Einstein summation convention, which means that every repeated index is summed over. In principle this should be done for each term separately, so your expression reads
$$
{R_{00}}=
\left(\sum_{\lambda=0}^3\Gamma^\lambda_{00,\lambda}\right)
-\left(\sum_{\lambda=0}^3\Gamma^\lambda_{0\lambda,0}\right)
+\left(\sum_{\lambda=0}^3\sum_{\sigma=0}^3
     \Gamma^\lambda_{00}\Gamma^\sigma_{\lambda\sigma}\right)
-\left(\sum_{\lambda=0}^3\sum_{\sigma=0}^3
     \Gamma^\sigma_{0\lambda}\Gamma^\lambda_{0\sigma}\right).
$$
In practice, you can put all the $\lambda$ summations into a single one,
$$
{R_{00}}=
\sum_{\lambda=0}^3\left(
\Gamma^\lambda_{00,\lambda}
-\Gamma^\lambda_{0\lambda,0}
+\left(\sum_{\sigma=0}^3
     \Gamma^\lambda_{00}\Gamma^\sigma_{\lambda\sigma}\right)
-\left(\sum_{\sigma=0}^3
     \Gamma^\sigma_{0\lambda}\Gamma^\lambda_{0\sigma}\right)\right),
$$
and you can also combine the two terms with $\sigma$ in them,
$$
{R_{00}}=
\sum_{\lambda=0}^3\left(
\Gamma^\lambda_{00,\lambda}
-\Gamma^\lambda_{0\lambda,0}
+\sum_{\sigma=0}^3\left(
     \Gamma^\lambda_{00}\Gamma^\sigma_{\lambda\sigma}
-\Gamma^\sigma_{0\lambda}\Gamma^\lambda_{0\sigma}\right)\right).
$$
However, what you cannot do is take one big summation on both indices for all terms,
$$
{R_{00}}≠
\sum_{\lambda=0}^3\sum_{\sigma=0}^3\left(
\Gamma^\lambda_{00,\lambda}
-\Gamma^\lambda_{0\lambda,0}
+\Gamma^\lambda_{00}\Gamma^\sigma_{\lambda\sigma}
-\Gamma^\sigma_{0\lambda}\Gamma^\lambda_{0\sigma}\right),
$$
because then you're over-counting the first two terms. If you really feel like doing that, then you could write
$$
{R_{00}}=
\sum_{\lambda=0}^3\sum_{\sigma=0}^3\left(
\frac14\Gamma^\lambda_{00,\lambda}
-\frac14\Gamma^\lambda_{0\lambda,0}
+\Gamma^\lambda_{00}\Gamma^\sigma_{\lambda\sigma}
-\Gamma^\sigma_{0\lambda}\Gamma^\lambda_{0\sigma}\right),
$$
but unless that form has very specific advantages there's usually no real reason to do that.